# Ruby on Rails - Displaying a user names on a new page/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**QUESTION: How can I have a new page, with a new controller, display information from my database?**

So I am creating a page that will display a list of users and their names in a table.

I created this new page using:

```
rails generate controller Information users
```

And created the appropriate routes. Now, on the html.erb of this page (users.html.erb):

I have:

```
<h1>Information#users</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/information/users.html.erb</p>
```

I want to do something like this in the page:

```
<%= @users.name %>
```

To display the users name.

My controller is:

```
class InformationController < ApplicationController
  def users
    @current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

And the users scheme database is:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

So what should I be doing to have the users.html.erb page display users information on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display a list of users. For that first collect all users in `users` action of `InformationController` which now look like

```
class InformationController < ApplicationController
  def users
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Now in `users.html.erb` you will have to loop through each user to display it in a  table

```
<h1>Information#users</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Choose a better name for your controller and instance variable

I'd be very careful with your naming scheme. Your controller action is called `users` however you are only displaying the information about the `current_user`. Your instances variable again is pluralized but it should be singular.

It should be this:

```
<%= @current_user.name %>
```

And then this:

```
class InformationController < ApplicationController
  def users
    @current_user = current_user # should work if you are using the devise gem
  end
end
```

#### Notice Re: Limiting the Contagion of External Dependencies in your App

If you are using the `devise` gem, it has a very handy helper method called `current_user` exactly as you have specified. Set it to an instance variable as above and use the `@current_user` variable throughout your views. Why? For academic and theoretical reasons when beginning your rails programming career: devise is an external dependency - the gem might change how the `current_user` helper method works or operates, it might change it's name to something else. If and when that happens, you will want to limit any negative consequential effects to your rails app. The only change you will need to make will be in the controller to this line `@current_user  = current user # i.e. the devise helper method`, rather than in the views, which would be the case if you had used `current_user` all over the place. Granted, the changes of this happening are microscopic, but it's a decision you need to be aware of that you are making, rather than passively making it.

Summary: use the devise gem (probably the most popular authentication gem out there) and it should be trivially easy.